# How to read a running Mono/Unity game process memory using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, readprocessmemory

I'm sorry if this is not the right forum for this question, but I can't really find a better place for it (I tried to [ask on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/6gaslt/reading_the_memory_of_a_process_running_mono_in_c/) some time ago but without success), so here I go.

I'm building a game companion app that aims to provide some information to the player about the current state of the game. This information is only accessible by reading the game's memory (it is compliant with the game's ToS by the way).

The game has been built in Unity, and my app is in C#. And I'm struggling to find any good documentation / entry point to how to achieve this.
The only pointers I got were about CheatEngine, but this looks very brittle compared to accessing Mono's structure directly.

Edit: I've started building a GitHub repo to document my progress: https://github.com/sebastientromp/unity-memory-reading-step-by-step.
It's still very much a work in progress, so please don't hesitate to comment or offer some help :)

As shown in [my main class](https://github.com/sebastientromp/unity-memory-reading-step-by-step/blob/master/MindVision/New/Main.cs), this is where I am today (comments removed):

```
static void Main()
{
    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Hearthstone").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("Hearthstone process: " + process);

    IntPtr processHandle = process.Handle;
    Console.WriteLine("Process Handle: " + processHandle);

    ProcessModule monoModule = process.Modules
        .OfType<ProcessModule>()
        .FirstOrDefault(module => module.ModuleName == "mono.dll");

    long monoModuleBaseAddress = monoModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64();
    Console.WriteLine("monoModuleBaseAddress: " + monoModuleBaseAddress);

    byte[] monoModuleContent = new byte[monoModule.ModuleMemorySize];
    Console.WriteLine("monoModuleContent: " + monoModuleContent);

    ReadBytes(processHandle, monoModuleBaseAddress, monoModuleContent);

    int imageDosHeaderElfanew = BitConverter.ToInt32(monoModuleContent, (int)Offsets.ImageDosHeader_e_lfanew);
    Console.WriteLine("imageDosHeaderElfanew: " + imageDosHeaderElfanew);

    int exportDirectoryAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(
        monoModuleContent, 
        imageDosHeaderElfanew + (int)Offsets.ImageNTHeaders_ExportDirectoryAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("exportDirectoryAddress: " + exportDirectoryAddress);

    var functionAddressMap = MapAllExportFunctions(monoModuleBaseAddress, monoModuleContent, exportDirectoryAddress);

    long monoRootDomainFunctionAddress;
    functionAddressMap.TryGetValue("mono_get_root_domain", out monoRootDomainFunctionAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("Mono rot domain address: " + monoRootDomainFunctionAddress);

    var functionContent = new byte[4];
    ReadBytes(processHandle, monoRootDomainFunctionAddress, functionContent);
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", functionContent));

    var rootDomainPointer = BitConverter.ToInt32(functionContent, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("rootDomainPointer: " + rootDomainPointer);
    ReadBytes(processHandle, rootDomainPointer, functionContent);
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", functionContent)); // This gives me [0,0,0,0] -> error!
}
```

That last line clearly shows there is an error somewhere, so I suppose it must be the way I read the function from its address.
Do you have any idea what I should be doing instead?

Comment: Try asking the developers for a built-in api. Otherwise, you cant do this from plain C# you will need to use some native methods. Try it with this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I should indeed have made the question clearer ; I am using ReadProcessMemory, but then am stuck about how to navigate Mono's memory structure. I have updated the question with the details I have

Comment: You will need to get the il code from the memory. And then read that, how to do that I dont know. But you can try mono.cecil, or try googling how to turn the raw bytes into il

Comment: Interesting question. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this. Maybe you can do something if you can get your hands on the gcroots but without information from the developers you'd have to figure out the structures yourself. As you yourself noted, I don't think you can count on fixed memory offsets, since the GC may move objects around even during runtime..

Comment: Thanks for the replies! From what I understand of Mono, the "root" (for lack of a better word) has arrays with the memory addresses of functions and entities - so I should be able to get that without relying on fixed offsets. Then each "entity" is a Mono object, and I assume(though it needs to be verified, but it would be consistent with having the pointer to all entities in the root) the memory for each object is allocated in a contiguous way, so from then I should be able to rely on fixed offsets (I hope). But I still need to understand how to read Mono structure, which is where I'm stuck :)

Comment: I think the GC even has some freedom in how structures are laid out in memory (order of fields, padding, etc.) so I wouldn't count on the fixed offsets..

Comment: Something like this might be worth a try: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16481/NET-Object-Spy-and-InvokeRemote (assuming this can be done on your target platform)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it looks like giving it a deeper look. From what I understand this works via code injection? This, unlike reading, is against the game's ToS, but understanding how they do it could definitely help

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly, this works via code injection. If you could execute a method from within the target process, you could read all the information you need via reflection (I guess). But this method would have to be infected, even though it would just read stuff.

Comment: Thanks - this is unfortunately not an option for me then. I'm having a look at Mono.Cecil, otherwise I'll have to rely on `ReadProcessMemory`, which means I'll have to navigate manually the whole Mono structure. I'll try and build a Github repo to document what I'm doing and make it easier for others to help

Comment: I read some more about Mono.Cecil, and it looks like this will be the same issue. It seems to actually let you understand the underlying structure, but not read from memory itself unless you inject your own code in the dll to do so, which I can't do. So I guess I'm back to native and ReadProcessMemory

Comment: I've added some code to show what I'm doing an where I'm stuck at the moment